# Drupal 9 doesn't parse DSN via drush

Tags: drupal, drupal-9, drush

We ran into an issue and I'm curious if others have as well.

We are running CiviCRM (5.61.4) on Drupal 9. Our DB is hosted on a different server from the application. From the UI, Civi is working fine. When we run `drush updatedb` from the CLI it crashes with an error in `vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Install/Requirements.php:136`.

Tracing that error I found that it's failing during the DB check. At the point of failure the DB host parameter is reverting to the default `localhost`. Interestingly, the CMS DB parameters remain intact -- only the CiviCRM host parameter is reset.

Upon further investigation I found that those parameters are loaded several times and initially are set correctly from the civicrm.settings.php file. But at some point in the cycle they revert to the default value -- which prevents the connection and thus the error.

I've been troubleshooting for a while, but haven't been able to pin down the place where that value gets incorrectly set. I'm wondering if anyone else has a similar setup and has run into this? Again -- it only happens via Drush -- the UI loads without issue.